# 1/3 area of isoceles triangle at height "a" with given base b and height h

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

I was thinking of interesting and difficult geometry problems to attempt to solve when I came up with this:

> Given and isosceles triangle with given base b and height h, find at what height, a, the area under a is equal to one third the area of the original triangle, in terms of b and h. [Here is a diagram of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHVlJ.png). Hope that you find this interesting and come up with a solution in terms of b and h.

Have fun!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Find an expression to represent at what height, a, is the area of the triangle under "a" 1/3 the area of the whole triangle.

Comment: So essentially the triangle above $a$ is $\frac 23 \frac 12bh$?

Comment: Yes. The upper, similar triangle's area is 2/3 *1/2*bh

Comment: This isn't too good of a "recreational-math" question. It feels more like a touch high-school geometry exercise.

Answer (score 2):

The upper triangle is similar to the larger triangle and their area ratio is $\frac{2}{3}$. Their length ratio is therefore $\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}$. 
$$\frac{h-a}{h} = \frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}$$
$$h - a = \frac{\sqrt{2}\cdot h}{\sqrt3}$$
$$a = h - \frac{\sqrt{2}\cdot h}{\sqrt3}$$

$$a = h\left (1 - \frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt3} \right)$$

Comment: Tip: `\sqrt{2}`. Or use `\sqrt2` if the operand is single-digit.